# Are the Big-O notations for the following programs correct?

Tags: python, time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

I have the following three programs and I have calculated the Big-O time complexity for each of them. I just want to make sure that I have done it right.

```
import random

def A(N):

      L=[]

      for i in range(0,26):
            L.append(chr(ord('A')+i))
      Alpha=[]
      i = 0
      while i< N:
            flag = 0
            x = random.randint(0,N-1)
            for j in range(0,i):
                  if Alpha[j] == L[x]:
                        flag = 1
                        break

            if flag == 0:
                  Alpha.append(L[x])
                  i = i + 1
      return Alpha
```

**Complexity for A(N) is [O(1) + O(n) + O(n)] -> O(n^2)**

```
def A2(N):

      L=[]

      x = ord('A')
      for i in range(0,26):
            L.append(chr(x+i))
      Alpha=[]
      i = 0
      Ran = [0]*N
      while i< N:
            x = random.randint(0,N-1)
            if Ran[x] == 0 :
                  Alpha.append(L[x])
                  i=i+1
                  Ran[x]=1
      return Alpha
```

**Complexity for A2(N) is [O(1) + O(n)] -> O(n)**

```
def A3(N):

      L=[]

      x = ord('A')
      for i in range(0,26):
            L.append(chr(x+i))
      Alpha=[]
      for i in range(0,N):
            Alpha.append(L[i])
      for i in range(2,N):
            x= random.randint(0,i)
            temp = Alpha[i]
            Alpha[i]= Alpha[x]
            Alpha[x] = temp
      return Alpha
```

**Complexity for A3(N) is [O(1) + O(n) + O(n)] -> O(n^2)**

Comment: didn't read the code but: [O(1) + O(n) + O(n)] -> **O(n)**

Answer (score 4):

In the *first example*, the complexity is **not**

> [O(1) + O(n) + O(n)] -> O(n^2)

but it's **[O(1) + sum from i=0 to O(n) of [O(n)]]** = sum from i=0 to O(n) of [O(n)] = O(n^2)

In practice, you are executing a O(n) task a maximum of n times - therefore, O(n) times. That's why this is, effectively, a multiplication.

---

In the *second example*, you would be correct if the execution of the loop wouldn't rely on random numbers - thanks to Nick Vitha for pointing that out, see [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55580530/8434333) - but, unfortunately, it does.

Algorithmic time complexity is usually applied to *deterministic algorithms*, and here we're talking about a *probabilistic algorithm*, which is modeled in a [different way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistic_Turing_machine). 
In this case, it's not trivial to get the complexity class, as it depends on the implementation of the random function and on its distribution.

Your [randomized algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomized_algorithm) doesn't have either a guarantee of success or a bounded run time, so the complexity class *should* be undefined, but it would need to be proven stochastically. Moreover, the *expected value of the time complexity* should be easier to calculate, given the distribution of the random function.

---

In the *third example*, it **is indeed**:

> [O(1) + O(n) + O(n)]

but when you add similar classes together you get the same class of time complexity - this is because you would get a multiple of the initial complexity, which in the asymptotic context is equal to it.
So the solution would be:

[O(1) + O(n) + O(n)] -> O(n)

---

I apologize if, mathematically speaking, my notation is not precise, but I believe that it summarizes the concept enough.

Comment: I would like to know from some meta-pros which kind of formatting style I should use to answer this kind of questions, thanks! Edits are appreciated.

Comment: I think the 2nd one is incorrect. See my answer as to why I think that is.

Comment: @NickVitha I agree. I have mistakenly seen the `i = i + 1` *outside* the random-dependant `if` for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

1.

> Complexity for A(N) is [O(1) + O(n) + O(n)] -> O(n^2)

This is not correct. Well, the O(n^2) part is correct, but how you got to it is untrue.

[O(1) + O(n) + O(n)] -> O(2n + 1) -> O(n)

However, your code is:

**[O(k) + O(n)*O(n)] -> O(n^2 + k) -> O(n^2)**

where k is a constant (in this case 26, but it doesn't matter as long as it's not influenced by n). You *multiply* things that are nested like that. You can simplify O(k) to O(1) if you want. Either way it goes away.

2.

> Complexity for A2(N) is [O(1) + O(n)] -> O(n)

Oh god. I am not even sure where to begin to start.

So basically, you're accessing a random part of an array of length `N`. And you're checking if it's 0. If it is, you do some stuff and assign it to 1.

I'm inclined to believe that the answer to this will be significantly higher than O(n) on average. Someone that's had more coffee and/or math experience will probably need to chime in to that, but you're going to loop through AT LEAST n times and AT WORST this loop will be infinite because you're doing random access and could just keep randomly checking a number that is 1. Usually, you do O() notation using WORST, so this loop is

O(infinity) -> **undefined**

3.

> Complexity for A3(N) is [O(1) + O(n) + O(n)] -> O(n^2)

As said before, it *is* [O(1) + O(n) + O(n)], but that yields **O(n)**

Answer (score 0):

For A2, I agree with Nick that it is unbounded (worst case). Your avg case is n * Log(n). Your O(n) is actually the best case.